# How to recombine split sentences?

Tags: pdf, nlp, sentence

I am processing PDFs that have been converted to text. The problem? Sometimes a sentence gets split due to wonky PDF formatting and/or PDF-to-text conversion.

So I'm looking for tools that help "reassemble" sentences that got split apart. Page headers or footers often are the culprits. Other elements, such as figures and charts, can come into play as well, but they are not my primary concern right now.

This problem can be tackled in a few ways:

1. Removing headers and footers before doing NLP sentence detection would certainly help. I don't know of tools that do this. Do you know of tools or methods? (The general idea to remove page numbers is "easy" in theory: find consecutive increasing numbers that occur about once per page.)
2. Using NLP parsers that can judge the likelihood that a sentence is grammatically correct would help. That way I can compare the grammatical correctness of two sentences taken separately in comparison with the correctness of their amalgamation. (The Stanford Parser, as I understand it, does not evaluate grammatical correctness.) Do you know of tools that can help?

Please let me know if you have suggestions, answers, or other ways to approach the problem.

Comment: It's hard to offer much advice without some example input. What does an interrupted sentence look like? If it's broken by a header or footer are there a lot of spaces? Why would a sentence be split without a header or footer?

Comment: @polm23 Here is some Ruby for you: s = "Just start with any arbitrary sentence. Insert some newlines and a page number in the middle somewhere."; s.insert(29, "\n\n3\n\n");

Comment: Thank you. If that's a typical you can find lines that don't end in punctuation and then remove all following lines until you encounter one with letters. Something like `s/\([!?.]\)\n[^A-z]*/\1 /g`.

Comment: [Welcome to Stackoverflow.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 1):

use Apache Tika to extract the data from a pdf.